# Converting click to hover event javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate on hover a burger bar, I found an example online and managed to get it working on mouseenter, but I want it to go back to the burger bar after the mouse has left the burger bar on mouseleave.

Here is the code, as you can see mouseenter works but when I move the mouse away I want it to go back to the burger bar and not remain as an X.

```js
(function() {"use strict";
  var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");
  for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var toggle = toggles[i];
    toggleHandler(toggle);
  };
  function toggleHandler(toggle) {
    toggle.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active"): this.classList.add("is-active");
    });
  }
             
})();
```

```css
.c-hamburger {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 66px;
  height: 55px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.c-hamburger:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.c-hamburger span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  right: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
}

.c-hamburger span::before,
.c-hamburger span::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  content: "";
}

.c-hamburger span::before {
  top: -10px;
}

.c-hamburger span::after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
.c-hamburger--htx {
  background-color: white;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span {
  transition: background 0s 0.3s;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before,
.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before {
  transition-property: top, transform;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  transition-property: bottom, transform;
}

/* active state, i.e. menu open */
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active {
  background-color: white;
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span {
  background: none;
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::before,
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::after {
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx">
  <span>toggle menu</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the class on `mouseenter` and remove it on `mouseleave`

```js
(function() {"use strict";
  var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");
  for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var toggle = toggles[i];
    toggleHandler(toggle);
  };
  function toggleHandler(toggle) {
    toggle.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.classList.add('is-active');
    })
    toggle.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(e) {
      this.classList.remove('is-active');
    });
  }
             
})();
```

```css
.c-hamburger {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 66px;
  height: 55px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.c-hamburger:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.c-hamburger span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  right: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
}

.c-hamburger span::before,
.c-hamburger span::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  content: "";
}

.c-hamburger span::before {
  top: -10px;
}

.c-hamburger span::after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
.c-hamburger--htx {
  background-color: white;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span {
  transition: background 0s 0.3s;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before,
.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before {
  transition-property: top, transform;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  transition-property: bottom, transform;
}

/* active state, i.e. menu open */
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active {
  background-color: white;
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span {
  background: none;
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::before,
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::after {
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx">
  <span>toggle menu</span>
</button>
```

You can also do this with CSS only.

```css
.c-hamburger {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 66px;
  height: 55px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.c-hamburger:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.c-hamburger span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  right: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
}

.c-hamburger span::before,
.c-hamburger span::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  content: "";
}

.c-hamburger span::before {
  top: -10px;
}

.c-hamburger span::after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
.c-hamburger--htx {
  background-color: white;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span {
  transition: background 0s 0.3s;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before,
.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before {
  transition-property: top, transform;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  transition-property: bottom, transform;
}

/* active state, i.e. menu open */
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active {
  background-color: white;
}

.c-hamburger--htx:hover span {
  background: none;
}

.c-hamburger--htx:hover span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.c-hamburger--htx:hover span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.c-hamburger--htx:hover span::before,
.c-hamburger--htx:hover span::after {
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx">
  <span>toggle menu</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I totally agree with you @Michael Coker :-)

Comment: Oh brilliant @michael-coker, I think I will go with the CSS one. Is there a difference between using JavaScript and CSS?

Comment: @Dino in your example, not really. Functionally it's about the same. But it's simpler, less code, and more direct to use CSS `:hover` than adding/removing a class on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` via JS. It's also a little more accessible.

Comment: OK thanks @Michael Corker, but I have this linked to a drop down menu, and when I go down to the menu the X goes back to the burger bar, so I amended the CSS to include .dropdown-content:hover.... where all the .c-hamburger--htx:hover.... code is and that did not work. Can you advise? the .dropdown-content contains all the menu <li> items.

Comment: I have an example here: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/protonus/pen/vgwZpx)

Comment: @Dino it's bad etiquette to ask for additional solutions in the comments. If you have a new issue, you should submit a new question. That said, trigger the change on the parent element, not the hamburger http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/NdVgZe

Comment: @Michael Coker, ah OK, next time I will ask a new question. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dino my pleasure.